Nautilus doesn't run after upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04
Running from the terminal:
** Message: 09:59:50.461: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nautilus-gsconnect'
GSConnect: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GSConnect'
Namespace Nautilus is already loaded with version 4.0

No window opens.
Tried nautilus -q, apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^, dpkg-reconfigure gdm3, apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt remove python3-nautilus solved this.
